Trino load testing returns SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE
I am running a simple load test with concurrent queries on Trino, and the majority of the requests succeed. However, the failed ones relate to the following logs' entries:

2024-05-03 07:13:08 2024-05-03T05:13:08.691Z    WARN    ContinuousTaskStatusFetcher-20240503_051240_01897_g7z4z.4.0.0-4111      io.trino.server.remotetask.RequestErrorTracker       Error getting task status 20240503_051240_01897_g7z4z.4.0.0:
http://172.31.0.10:8080/v1/task/20240503_051240_01897_g7z4z.4.0.0
2024-05-03 07:13:08
io.trino.server.remotetask.SimpleHttpResponseHandler$ServiceUnavailableException:
Server returned SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE:
http://172.31.0.10:8080/v1/task/20240503_051240_01897_g7z4z.4.0.0/status
2024-05-03 07:13:08     at
io.trino.server.remotetask.SimpleHttpResponseHandler.onSuccess(SimpleHttpResponseHandler.java:52)
2024-05-03 07:13:08     at
io.trino.server.remotetask.SimpleHttpResponseHandler.onSuccess(SimpleHttpResponseHandler.java:27)
2024-05-03 07:13:08     at
com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:1137)
2024-05-03 07:13:08     at
io.airlift.concurrent.BoundedExecutor.drainQueue(BoundedExecutor.java:79)
2024-05-03 07:13:08     at
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
2024-05-03 07:13:08     at
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
2024-05-03 07:13:08     at
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1570)
2024-05-03 07:13:08
2024-05-03 07:13:08
2024-05-03 07:13:08 2024-05-03T05:13:08.597Z    WARN
ContinuousTaskStatusFetcher-20240503_051244_01926_g7z4z.5.0.0-1027
io.trino.server.remotetask.RequestErrorTracker       Error getting
task status 20240503_051244_01926_g7z4z.5.0.0:
http://172.31.0.10:8080/v1/task/20240503_051244_01926_g7z4z.5.0.0
2024-05-03 07:13:08
io.trino.server.remotetask.SimpleHttpResponseHandler$ServiceUnavailableException:
Server returned SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE:
http://172.31.0.10:8080/v1/task/20240503_051244_01926_g7z4z.5.0.0/status
2024-05-03 07:13:08     at
io.trino.server.remotetask.SimpleHttpResponseHandler.onSuccess(SimpleHttpResponseHandler.java:52)
2024-05-03 07:13:08     at
io.trino.server.remotetask.SimpleHttpResponseHandler.onSuccess(SimpleHttpResponseHandler.java:27)
2024-05-03 07:13:08     at
com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:1137)
2024-05-03 07:13:08     at
io.airlift.concurrent.BoundedExecutor.drainQueue(BoundedExecutor.java:79)
2024-05-03 07:13:08     at
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
2024-05-03 07:13:08     at
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
2024-05-03 07:13:08     at
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1570)

The error is:

io.trino.server.remotetask.SimpleHttpResponseHandler$ServiceUnavailableException:
Server returned SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE:

Which config.properties settings should I fine-tune to increase the HTTP throughput?

I think you are encountering a 'service unavailable' error because your coordinator may be running out of resources. You can try adding node-scheduler.include-coordinator=false. After doing this, no work will be scheduled on the coordinator. Please check and let me know if this resolves the issue."

It is a hint in the right direction, thanks. I am testing on a local machine with bare minimum resources, so I don't expect the errors to go away entirely, but this trick reduce the rate of failures.
